# Link on image is too wide

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just added this button to the header of my site but the actual link associated to it can be clicked anywhere along the width of the header container. Is there an easy way to make this work just on the image itself?

http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/

pw = amazinggraphics

I feel I am missing something simple here...

Comment: Please post relevant code here.   You cannot expect us to dig through the code on your website.

Comment: #logo-container a : this has width 100%; so its but obvious. make a class for the button and make it float right

Comment: My Australian internet refuses to load it and I'm not going to sift through your code. **Post relevant code, please**.

Comment: Sorry guys - I wasn't being lazy I just didn't know what to post. I think I found it now. This is from the "header" div in header.php:

    <div id="logo-container"><a href="http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk"><img src="http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ZCF_Nexa_pinkgrey-31.png" alt="" /></a><a href="http://www.growing-underground.com" class="stamp"><img src="http://www.zerocarbonfood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/GU-darkgreen.png"></a></div>

And this is the corresponding CSS:

    .stamp img {clear:left;float:right;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use this code

```
#logo-container{
    position: relative;
}

.stamp{
    width: auto !important;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 100px;
}
```

hope this will help you. Now only image is clickable )

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my original question being so incomplete.